# Is it safe to use open to open links

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to use `window.open` function just as `open` in browser? Using `open('http://stackoverflow.com/')` pretty works for me, but is it really safe and what side-effects does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All properties of the global object—`window` in the case of browsers—are accessible in the global scope and every scope therein unless a variable is declared with the same name. If for some reason a variable is created anywhere in the scope chain named `open`, then the reference to `window.open` will no longer be accessible without using `window`.

```js
console.log(open);
(function() {
  var open = 'Hello World!';
  console.log(open, window.open);
})();
```